# Verify that $f(x,y)=a^{x}(1-a)^{y}$ is a joint density function

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $a \in$ (0,1) and $f(x,y)=a^{x}(1-a)^{y}$ para $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

Show that f is a function density

$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}a^{x}(1-a)^{y}$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{y=0}^{\infty}a^{x}(1-a)^{y}=\frac{a^x}{a}$

And

$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^x}{a}=\frac{1}{a(1-a)}$

use the geometry series, but must be one :(, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Apparently the author does not include zero among the natural numbers.  For $\lvert a\rvert\lt 1$:$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty a^x = \dfrac{a}{1-a}\\\sum_{y=1}^\infty (1-a)^y = \dfrac{1-a}{a}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(x,y)$ is meant to be a joint PMF (not a density), so you should be summing over $x,y \in \mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3\ldots\}$ rather than taking integrals. If you modify your work by changing the integrals to sums, you'll get the desired result of $1$.